# Close application opened in .NET console application

Tags: c#, console-application, system.diagnostics

I'm opening an external application from a console application, as follows:

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "SomeApp.exe"
    }
};

p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
p.CloseMainWindow(); //Bam!! InvalidOperationExcetion
```

How can I close SomeApp.exe? I'm building some automation around this application and I would like it do be closed whenever I'm done with it, but I haven't been successful so far.
`p.CloseMainWindow()` throws an exception of type InvalidOperationException with message "Cannot process request because the process (1216) has exited."

I'm not killing the process and I don't know what is killing it.
I'm running this console application from Visual Studio in Administrator mode.

Any ideas? Thanks you in advance

Comment: if `p.Kill()` throws an exception, maybe `p` is not running at that point? (i.e, it finished it's work before you called `Kill()`, by the way, it'd help if you could tell us what's the exception you're getting

Comment: What exception.. maybe you just don't have the right credentials

Comment: Which exception do you get? Can you provide that in your question please?

Comment: Updated. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: What happens when you double click on the application in Windows Explorer? Run it from a command line (cmd.exe) and see what is the output of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `.WaitForExit()` your current process waits until the external application is closed. There is no point in calling `.Kill()` afterwards, because the process is already gone. A simple example:

```
        var p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo =
            {
                FileName = "cmd.exe"
            }
        };

        p.Start();  

        Console.WriteLine("press any key to kill the other app");
        Console.ReadKey();
        if (!p.HasExited)
        {
            p.Kill();
            Console.WriteLine("other app was killed");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("other app was already dead");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Depending on what you want, you may as well just skip the call to `.Kill()` in your current code - as I've mentioned, the external process is already gone after `.WaitForExit()`.

Comment: There is no point in starting a process from another thread! It starts in it's own process!

Comment: I figured what was the problem. I am the problem :) I was opening the app through a shortcut, not the actual exe. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

The call to `WaitForExit()` blocks the calling thread until the process exits. So there is nothing to kill afterwards!

You can check for the sate of the thread before calling `Kill()` using `HasExited` property, and call `ClsoeMainWindow()` to close the application. If that didn't work, `Kill` the process:

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "SomeApp.exe"
    }
};

p.Start();

// Do whatever...

if (!p.HasExited)
{
    if (!p.CloseMainWindow())
        p.Kill();
}
```

Comment: The process is killed right after the p.Start, therefore I can't close the application that I opened because the process has been killed. This doesn't solve the problem but thank you for the help.

Comment: Who kills the process? Does it finish working and closes itself? Is it the required behaviour? You wanted to close the application, and it is closed! What's the problem?

Comment: I updated my question. I open an application, SomeApp.exe, the process gets killed somehow but SomeApp.exe is still running. I want to close SomeApp.exe. Does it make sense?

Comment: I figured what was the problem. I am the problem :) I was opening the app through a shortcut, not the actual exe. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

This will ask the application to close - this will allow it to ask the user if they want to save any open documents etc.

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "SomeApp.exe",
        ErrorDialog = true
    }
};

p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);//or do whatever you need with the application
p.CloseMainWindow();
p.WaitForExit();
```

This will just end the process. You still have to `WaitForExit()` because `Process.Kill()` runs asynchronously

```
var p = new Process
{
    StartInfo =
    {
        FileName = "SomeApp.exe",
        ErrorDialog = true
    }
};

p.Start();
Thread.Sleep(5000);//or do whatever you need with the application
p.Kill();
p.WaitForExit();
```

*update: added `ErrorDialog = true` to show a message if there is a problem starting the application*

Comment: The process is killed right after p.Start, therefore I can't close the application that I opened. When it gets to p.CloseMainWindow() the process has been killed. Any other ideas? :) Thanks for the reply

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the application you're trying to start then - does it require any parameters? Try setting the ErrorDialog property of the StartInfo object to true.

Comment: I figured what was the problem. I am the problem :) I was opening the app through a shortcut, not the actual exe. Thanks for the help